# Running .exe files in a GitLab pipeline

Tags: python, powershell, gitlab

I'm new to GitLab, so my apologies if this has an obvious solution. Thanks in advance for your help!

No matter what I try, I can't seem to run an `.exe` file within a GitLab pipeline.

I've created a GitLab pipeline using GitLab Runner hosted on my Windows machine with a powershell type executor. Every stage of the pipeline works perfectly and executes a number of Python scripts on my Windows machine without any issue except for one pipeline stage that requires running an `.exe` file.

The executable is supposed to create several files in a directory on the Windows machine and works perfectly if run in powershell from a local script. However, the executable has no effect and produces no output if I try to run it from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
script:
   - C:\path.exe -o config_file_for_executable.config
   - python build.py
```

I've also tried running the exe in the pipeline with `powershell path.exe` and with the Python subprocesses module, which also has no effect. After "running" the executable and passing onto the next script, the pipeline stage continues to the Python script on the next line, which executes successfully, and the pipeline stage passes, but the executable has no effect, produces no output, and does not appear to run. I've also tried running other executable files with the runner, which also have no effect.

I'm probably overlooking something simple, but no executable file that I run from gitlab actually executes, even though the same .exe works perfectly when run locally from powershell on my runner machine outside of GitLab. How can I run `.exe` files from within my GitLab pipeline with a powershell type runner on a Windows machine? Do I need to configure some security or firewall setting on my Windows machine to allow remote execution of `.exe` files?

The `.exe` I am trying to run has a UI. Does that mean I need to use `psexec` or a similar program to execute it remotely on GitLab?

Comment: Always worse a try in YAML: put single quotation marks around the command.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion, @KlausD! I just tried single quotes and it still isn't working, but this was worth a shot. Any other ideas?

Comment: One more detail: the pipeline stage now occasionally works, albeit very infrequently. This leads me to think that there may be some issue with the runner. However, I have tried creating a new runner and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out not to be with the exe or the pipeline code but with an unhealthy runner executing the job that needed to be reconfigured and rebooted. I ran GitLab Runner in debug mode to fix the issues with the runner, rebooted it, and everything worked perfectly.